# How can i get the time of the call initiated?

Tags: android, call, duration

Im making an android app.I'll call from one device and receive on another, But can anyone tell me how can i get the time on Receiver Device at what time the Caller device initiated the call ? Because i want to calculate the delay when the call was dialed and when it was received ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call from one device you can store time at server end with help of api and when you receive call you can get again integrate api to get a time when  first device called u.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to get that , anyway without the server ?

Comment: You can use Firebase Database @MuhammadAbdullah

Answer (score 1):

You should create a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                // Phone number 
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                // Ringing state
                // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            // This code will execute when the call is answered or disconnected
        }

    }
}
```

You should register you application to listen to these intents in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

> In that you can save start time and off-hook time. Get difference
>   between this will be delay that you want.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i will broadcast an intent from the caller device and receive it on the receiver device and i can get time in that intent ? that is  what you mean right ?

Comment: Yes, OR you can save time when you call and second time you will save when off-hook mode active.